# Fixing POODLE Issue, need help on SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")

Tags: java, ssl

All,

Iam in process of fixing a security vulnerability issue(see below link) in code.
http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/10/this-poodle-bites-exploiting-ssl-30.html

At places we have used the below ssl context to make secure communications

SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")(package: javax.net.ssl).

1. I know getInstance takes a protocol string value, but question is what does "TLS" means by value, i.e., is it same as TLS1.0? Similarly what does "SSL" means by value, is it same as "SSLv3"?
2. Is there a way to mention "TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV" while creating the context to fix this vulnerability?  One way we are thinking is to disable ssl and use only TLS1.2, but to make it back ward compatible, is there a way to specify fall back option as mentioned in article, this option if any can be passed to api calls while creating ssl context?

Thanks!
Santhosh

Comment: See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SSLContext).

Comment: Doc says "Supports some version of SSL; may support other versions", its little confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on the same issue.  In short, `SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")` does not exclude `SSLv3` from the list of supported protocols.  You must use the `setEnabledProtocols()` method on `SSLServerSocket` or `SSLSocket` (whichever is appropriate to your usecase).